# xpath for parent a tag

Tags: xpath, scrapy

so I've been trying to scrape this without much luck. I have tried with the following xpaths with no luck:

1. ../@href
2. parent::a/@href

Here's what I'm trying to scrape:

```
<a href="https://placeholder.url.com" class="infoclass_3392 classghzb">
<div class="hgs-983hsa" data-testid="Name">Casing NZXT H510i Black Matte or White</div>
<div class="hgs-212gsa" data-testid="Price">Rp1.747.999</div>
</a>
```

I can scrape the price data, but from the price data I'm trying to access the parent a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current node is the `text()`, you need to go up two levels: `../../@href` or `parent::div/parent::a/@href`. The parent of the `text()` is the `div`.

Demonstated in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open file.xml ;
cd a/div[2]/text() ;
ls ;                                # Rp1.747.999
echo ../../@href ;                  # https://placeholder.url.com
echo parent::div/parent::a/@href ;  # https://placeholder.url.com
```